# Remote git branches not shown with `git branch -r`?

Tags: git

I have two directories on my local machine pointing to the same remote git repository.
When I issue the command `git branch -r` in one of the directories I get a longer list of remote branches then in the other directory.  How is that possible ?
It seems that some of the remote branches are 'hidden' in one directory and are visible in the other.

Comment: What do you mean by hidden in one directory and visible in the other?

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, couldn't get the remote branches on one of my local directories. `git branch -r` would show less branches and also not the top-most change, while on the other directory everything was refreshing nicely.

To fix this, I did `git config -l` on both directories and found out that I was missing the `remote.origin.fetch` setting. Running the following line fixed my problem:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git fetch 

From github.com:username/test2
   2bd5e5e..2619d39  master     -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      remotebr2  -> origin/remotebr2
 * [new branch]      remotebranch -> origin/remotebranch
```

Comment: This fixed my problem I was having when I create my repo through Aptana3

Answer (score 10):

I think you should fetch and prune:

```
prune 
Deletes all stale tracking branches under <name>. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by <name>, but are still locally available in "remotes/<name>". 

With --dry-run option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.
```

With this commandlines:

```
git fetch
git remote prune origin
```

Answer (score 2):

Are both repositories up-to-date? Try running `git fetch` and see if that fixes it.